# Can ReduceByKey param mutate first argument?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

`PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey` scaladoc states

> To avoid memory allocation, both of these functions are allowed to modify and return their first argument instead of creating a new U.

It is essential to take advantage of this when memory allocation becomes a blocker.

However, `PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey` scaladoc does not contain the same sentence.

Both methods are implemented in terms of a common underlying method (`combineByKeyWithClassTag`), so the ability to use mutable structures should also hold. But `aggregateByKey` does some preliminary "cleaning" of the provided function that may or may not be relevant. (`self.context.clean(seqOp)`).

Is it OK to pass a function value for `seqOp` that mutates its first parameter to `reduceByKey`?